# How To Get All Link On Html Document Using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: html, python-2.7

how can i get all the link present in html file using `bs4`.
i am trying with this code but i am not getting the url

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = raw_input('enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print (url+tag.get('href',None))
```

Comment: You mean you want the entire `<a ...>` section?

Comment: i want only (http:// ....... ) format from the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`urlparse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin);

EDIT: To deduplicate, just put them in a set before display.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from urlparse import urljoin

urlInput = raw_input('enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(urlInput).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')    
urls = set()

for tag in tags:
     urls.add(urljoin(url, tag.get('href')))

for url in urls:
     print url
```

Comment: but there is duplication in links.

Comment: @gavisic You never mentioned that they should not be duplicated, but added code for that (adding the urls to a set, then displaying them from there)